# How to install wifi drivers without internet?

Tags: networking, drivers, package-management

I have a laptop that uses a RTL8723DU wifi chipset (driver: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723du). I couldn't find the driver in the installer, and the laptop does not have an ethernet port. The instructions in the driver say that I need to install gcc, make, and build-essential, but I don't know how to do that without internet.

I have a 16GB usb where I have cloned the repository (I think). I tried downloading the packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ on a different computer but it gives me an error when I try to install them with dpkg.

I.e., `dpkg-deb: error: 'gcc_11.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive`

apt doesn't work either.

I am new to ubuntu, so I don't know if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: dpkg-deb?? The correct command is `sudo dpkg -i some_package.deb`. You may also use wildcards: `sudo dpkg -i gcc*.deb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Saves yourself from headaches, frustrations and wasted time. Simply use USB tethering from your phone if you have to install something online. Not having Ethernet is not a limitation nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of downloading the packages on another device and installing them with `dpkg` should work fine for getting them without an internet connection - the only issue here appears to be with the `.deb` file itself. The error message seems to suggest that the file may not have been downloaded correctly, so redownloading it could solve your problem. (You can check for an incomplete/wrong download by running `sha256sum gcc_11.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` - the correct SHA256 checksum is listed on the page you downloaded the package from.)

Comment: The error is actually in the command used, **as already commented**. And your answer doesn't account for dependencies. Installing stuff offline is possible but you can easily find yourself in dependency hell.